# How to get multiple pages of a website to scrape specific data when only the domain link is known using python and beautifulsoap

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python **scraping** and want to write code to **scrape** data of a website and it's all inner page when no pagination available and page links are dynamic you can see the link which i've posted where i'm trying to collect information of a company,name,address and phone number
Here is my code.

I've try lots of questions from stackoverflow but they didn't match my requirement.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source= requests.get('http://businessdirectory.pk/Default.aspx?action=Business&pid=762390').text

soup= BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
ParentDiv= soup.find('div' , class_='businessDetails')
CompanyName= ParentDiv.find('p' , class_='title').text
CityName= ParentDiv.find('p' , class_='cityName').text
CityAddress= ParentDiv.find('p' , class_='address').text
PhoneNumber= ParentDiv.find('p' , class_='phone').text
MobileNo= ParentDiv.find('p' , class_='mobNo').text
print(CompanyName)
print(CityName)
print(CityAddress)
print(PhoneNumber)
```

All  i want to give just a link of domain and it will get all inner page and search for the same data there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code hope this helps.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page_num = 0

company_name=[]
City_Name=[]
City_Address=[]
Phone_Number=[]
Maxpage=12
while page_num<Maxpage:
    page = "http://businessdirectory.pk/Default.aspx?action=Business&pid=762390&page={}".format(page_num)
    pageTree = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.text, 'html.parser')
    ParentDiv = soup.find('div', class_='businessDetails')

    CompanyName = ParentDiv.find('p', class_='title').text
    CityName = ParentDiv.find('p', class_='cityName').text
    CityAddress = ParentDiv.find('p', class_='address').text
    PhoneNumber = ParentDiv.find('p', class_='phone').text

    company_name.append(CompanyName)
    City_Name.append(CityName)
    City_Address.append(CityAddress)
    Phone_Number.append(PhoneNumber)
    page_num += 1


print(company_name)
print(City_Name)
print(City_Address)
print(Phone_Number)
```

Output will be like this.

```
['Ab Traders', 'Al Faisal Machinery Store', 'Ameen Pipe Store', 'Aslam Air Compressor', 'Best Engineering Works', 'China Center', 'Empyrean Group', 'General Industrial Corporation', 'Habib Mill Store', 'Humayun Traders', 'Islam Air Corporation', 'Khalid Hussain Workshop 3']
['Faisalabad', 'Faisalabad', 'Faisalabad', 'Faisalabad', 'Faisalabad', 'Faisalabad', 'Lahore', 'Faisalabad', 'Faisalabad', 'Faisalabad', 'Faisalabad', 'Faisalabad']
['Sadiq Market, Railway Road', 'Railway Road', 'Sadiq Market, Railway Road', 'Railway Road', 'Sadiq Market, Railway Road', 'Railway Road', '8-E 1, Jagawar Chowk, Near Allah Hu Chowk, Johar Town', 'Sadiq Market, Railway Road', 'Railway Road', 'Sadiq Market, Railway Road', 'Railway Road', 'General Bus Stand']
['0412639166', '0412646985-2606985', '0412618759', '0412600387', '0412632037', '0412600504-2634502', '0336-9954475', '0412636174-2637446', '0412617274', '0412635348-2617469', '0412618242', '0418781513']
```

Comment: This is not what i really want. i can access all the data from a single page but i'm talking about the multi-page like e.g if i go the homepage of a website i want to collect all the data from the other page too like, about us posts and contact us etc.